# Is there a way to retrieve consumer lag from a given kafka topic using Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka and have a listener consuming messages from multiple topics, defined as :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {
"c1.ERROR","c2.ERROR","c3.ERROR" }, groupId = "g1", autoStartup = "false", id = "errorTopicsConsumer", containerFactory = "errorListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment)
```

My requirement is to retrieve the number of unconsumed messages[consumer lag] a given topic from this listener when a REST API is invoked passing the topic name as an input.

Basically I need something like:
`public int getUnconsumedMessagesCount(String topicName)`

I could not find a readily available method to achieve this using Spring Kafka.
I have tried this code snippets but it does not fit my requirement:

```
MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                .getListenerContainer("errorTopicsConsumer");
        Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = listenerContainer.metrics();
for (String consumer : metrics.keySet()) {

            System.out.println("L: " + metrics.get(consumer).entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().name().startsWith("records-lag"))
                    .map(entry -> entry.getValue().metricName().name() + " = " + entry.getValue().metricValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from Spring Actuator / JMX beans, rather than from the consumer instance itself

Lag is given by a group.id for all topics that group subscribe to, not only a topic name.

People commonly use Prometheus/InfluxDB+Grafana to visualize that data, outside of any one application